# error message not redirected to error-channel spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
/*Below Spring-integration configuration*/
/*Listener*/         
<!--Reading the Message from Queue as a Listener -->
<int-jms:inbound-gateway connection-factory="MQConnectionFactory"
   request-destination="ReadWsRequestQueue"
    request-channel="ReadWsInputChannel"
    transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"
    error-channel="errorReadChannel"/>

/*Processing Message*/
<!--Processing the message-->
<int:chain input-channel="ReadWsInputChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="ReadUnmarshaller"/>
    <int:transformer ref="RequestBuilder" method="build"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="ReadService" method="registerRead" />
    <int:transformer ref="ResponseBuilder" method="buildResponse"/>
    <int:transformer ref="ReadMarshaller"/>
    <int:transformer ref="toStringTransformer"/>

/*Error Channel config*/
<!--Error channel configuration -->
<int:channel id="errorReadChannel"/>
<int:chain input-channel="errorReadChannel">
    <int-jms:outbound-gateway id="jmsOutboundGateway"
        connection-factory="MQConnectionFactory" 
        request-destination="DLQErrorQueue" />
</int:chain>
```

Question:

In service Activator method we are throwing a RuntimeException, which should get redirected to the error channel??

All the exceptions should go to the error-channel,

Question 2.)

Also is there any way in Spring-integration by which we can forward the exception causing actual MQ message to a separate channel?

Comment: What version of Spring Integration? An exception will cause an `ErrorMessage` to be sent to the error channel; its payload is a `MessagingException` having two properties `failedMessage`  and `cause` (the exception). You can manipulate the ErrorMessage any way you want on the error flow. The failedMessage will be the message at the time of the failure (after your 2 transformers). If you want to save off the original message for error processing, add a header-enricher to save it off in a header (`<header name="foo" expression="payload" />`) before transforming. Available in `failedMessage`.

Comment: Spring integration version is 2.1, i do get the exception message but its not getting redirected to the error-channel. Error channel is empty even after the process is completed.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the error channel is empty". The error channel is a `DirectChannel` and has no capacity so it has no concept of "fullness". I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message flow. All should become clear.